# ChromeOptions not applying to Chrome webdriver on Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

```
options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "download.default_directory": "C:\\Download\\Directory",
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
})
options.add_argument("--start-maximize")
                                
driver = Chrome(options=options)
```

The Chrome window doesn't start maximized. Downloads still gets prompted every single time. Download prompt doesn't point to "default_directory".

I tried switching around between the Options, ChromiumOptions, ChromeOptions classes and nothing worked. I also tried switching between the "chrome_options" and the "options" arguments in the Chrome webdriver, still didn't work.

I couldn't confirm if the "executable_path" and "service" arguments of webdriver work because the webdriver ran without them. Though, using the "executable_path" argument triggered a deprecation warning.

Python 3.8.15
Selenium 4.9.1
ChromeDriver 113.0.5672.63 (0e1a4471d5ae5bf128b1bd8f4d627c8cbd55f70c-refs/branch-heads/5672@{#912})
Windows 10